# NTLM with Apache + CentOS 5

Tags: perl, apache2, centos, ntlm

I tried to install NTLM on CentOS 5 with Apache 2. 
I did the following steps.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/S/SP/SPEEVES/Apache2-AuthenNTLM-0.02.tar.gz
tar zxvf Apache2-AuthenNTLM-0.02.tar.gz
cd Apache2-AuthenNTLM-0.02
perl Makefile.pl
make install
```

After that I added to my httpd.conf the following:

```
<Directory “/var/www/htlm/secure”>
Options Indexes
PerlAuthenHandler Apache2::AuthenNTLM
AuthType ntlm,basic
AuthName Secure Access
require valid-user
PerlAddVar ntdomain “YOURDOMAIN domaincontroller backupdomaincontroller”
PerlSetVar defaultdomain YOURDOMAIN
PerlSetVar splitdomainprefix 1
PerlSetVar ntlmdebug 0
PerlSetVar ntlmauthoritative off
</Directory>
```

Now I tried to restart the httpd service but I got the following error:

```
service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 1018 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Invalid command 'PerlAuthenHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Do I need to add something else or do I need to add a module?

Thanks

Regards Paul

Comment: Unrelated to the actual issue, but consider that NTLM is depreciated in favour of Kerberos. There are also security considerations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum13/4292.htm, you need `mod_perl` too.